# Minty smelling plant with white and pink flowers

Tags: identification, herbs

This plant is growing in my garden and when the leaves are rubbed it smells minty. Can anyone identify it?

[image: plant2]
[image: plant1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. It's [Salvia "Hot Lips"](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2014/may/10/plant-of-week-salvia-hot-lips)

"Delicate red and white blooms create a stunning show throughout summer. Some flowers will bloom in solid red color attracting bees and hummingbirds. With a little protection, this Mexican introduction will happily over-winter in zone 6."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is Salvia 'Hot Lips' - the salvias include the sages, used in cooking, so what you're detecting isn't mint, but possibly a sage like scent.This one's not generally used for culinary purposes.

Comment: Salvia is a mint.

Comment: @Brenn No, its not - Mentha is mint, Salvia is sage, Salvia officinalis being the one mostly used in cooking. Both Salvia and Mentha belong to the Lamiaceae, but that's the only connection.

Comment: Sorry, but Salvia is a mint.

Comment: Please cite your source

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvia

Comment: Ah, Wiki as usual - Lamiacea is sometimes known as the 'mint family' but that doesn't make sage a mint any more than Lamium is a mint - the term 'mint family' is common usage - you will see it is not quoted as 'mint family' here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamium

Comment: If simple semantics are in play here, the Lamiacae Family IS the mint Family. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamiaceae. Sigh. This is trite of us.

Comment: Well, we'll leave it by agreeing to disagree - but I wouldn't fancy salvia or lamium sauce with my roast lamb just because they're commonly known as 'mint family'!

Comment: So, by that logic, mint is in the 'sage family'?

Comment: No, its in the Lamiaceae, though you could call it the Sage family if you like - if you want to refer to it as sage or mint or fred's family, you can, but Salvia is not the same as Mentha. And by the logic Brenn/Wiki is using, presumably a Pyracantha or Photinia are roses because, like roses, they belong to the Rosaceae family....

Comment: @Viv sorry, forgot to ping you when I answered...